# How to use pypy with Django along with postgresql backend?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cpython, pypy

Is there a way to install `psycopg2` with `pypy`. I am trying to run Django with `pypy` and the main problem I am facing is `psycopg2` library.

`pypy` documentation says that I can install `psycopg2cffi` library instead, but I don't know how to tell Django postgresql backend to use `psycopg2cffi` instead of `psycopg2`. Is there any way I can do that? Is there a way to install `psycopg2` with `pypy`. or more broadly, is there any advantage of using `pypy` than normal `Cpython` compiler with Django?

I tried running various python programs using both `Cpython` and `pypy` and shockingly `pypy` was much faster. So, I thought using `pypy` can actually increase the throughput of APIs by reducing the time of each API, but I haven't found any documentation for the same?

Any leads are welcome!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: > is there any advantage of using pypy than normal Cpython compiler with Django?
No

Comment: Don't be so negative. Pypy has several advantages and disadvantages over CPython.

Answer (score 0):

from:  https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2cffi/

> To use this package with Django or SQLAlchemy invoke a compatibility
>   hook (for example, from settings.py in case of Django, or from a
>   psycopg2.py file in site-packages of your virtual env):
>
> ```
> from psycopg2cffi import compat 
> compat.register()
> ```

Comment: I have tried this but it still gives the same error?